Disable popups when hovering over Outlook Calendar events
(Windows 10) Is there a way to turn off the popups that show when hovering over Calendar events?  They will generally obscure another appointment I'm also trying to see, and they only show me information I already see in the main Outlook window i.e. event name, organizer, and time.  I see no value in their content, and they're an annoyance to me multiple times per day.
Note that I do see "Show calendar details in ScreenTip" under "Options / Calendar / Scheduling assistant".  It sounds like it might control the hover popup, but unfortunately, it is already disabled.
